# Facebook Invite Friends With Random URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to keep a track of users referring other users to my website. So i want whenever a user invites his friends from facebook, the invitation link to contain his `userid`. Is it possible to send invites with random **urls**.

For eg : Right now the user gets the invitation link for **http://example.com** because that's what i have specified in my app site url.

I want the invitation link to be **http://example.com?referrer=joe**

Answer (score 0):

> I want the invitation link to be http://example.com?referrer=joe

And “joe” would be who or what here? If it’s the user sending the request – you have his id already, it’s in the request object details under `from`.

If you want to pass any other referential data – the Requests dialog has the `data` parameter for that. You can put any text data in there, up to 255 characters long. And when the user follows the request, you will get the request id[s] they are acting upon – and then you can read the request details from the API, and you will get that value you put into `data` back from there as well.

See docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: Thanks for the info... can you also tell me how do i read request details from the API

Comment: See 2nd link I posted, it’s explained there.

Answer (score -2):

Imagine, that you have JS function:

```
function invite(){

//number from 0 to 9
var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)); 

//get random param
var param = arrayOfDefinedParams[i]; 

//define request URL
var requestUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=<APP_ID>&message=<YOUR_MESSAGE>&redirect_uri=<URL_SET_IN_APP_DASHBOARD>/?param="+param;

//show modal window with request URL and random param
myWindow=window.open(requestUrl,'','width=400,height=300');

myWindow.focus();

}
```

All you have to do now, is binding `invite()` to `onclick` event on any element ;)

Comment: `redirect_uri` is where the user _sending_ the request will be directed to after finishing with the dialog. But that is not what’s been asked for here.

Comment: As @Pratic wrote: `Is it possible to send invites with random urls.`

Comment: Maybe your answer would be valid, if you take the question literally. But then it still does not make much sense, to do what you advised.